# sqoop import gives wrong result for a correct sql query

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop

I using a query like below in `MySQL` . I am getting my desired result.

```
select TABLE_NAME,count(column_name) as no_of_columns from information_schema.columns where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'testing' and TABLE_NAME NOT REGEXP 'temp|bkup|RemoveMe|test' group by TABLE_NAME
```

When I use the same query in a sqoop import statement then the results are different.

The `sqoop` import statement is below.

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://xxxxxx:3306/information_schema --username xxxxx --password-file /user/xxxxx/passwds/mysql.file --query "select TABLE_NAME,count(column_name) as no_of_columns from information_schema.columns where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'testing' and TABLE_NAME NOT REGEXP 'temp|bkup|RemoveMe|test' group by TABLE_NAME and \$CONDITIONS" -m 1 --target-dir /user/hive/warehouse/xxxx.db/testing_columns --outdir /home/xxxxx/logs/outdir
```

Why is this happening and what should I do in order to get desired result

Comment: Can you provide complete console output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$CONDITIONS` token must be in the `WHERE` clause:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://xxxxxx:3306/information_schema \
    --username xxxxx --password-file /user/xxxxx/passwds/mysql.file \
    --query "select TABLE_NAME,count(column_name) as no_of_columns \ 
               from information_schema.columns \
               where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'testing' \
                 and TABLE_NAME NOT REGEXP 'temp|bkup|RemoveMe|test' \ 
                 and \$CONDITIONS \
               group by TABLE_NAME" \
    -m 1 --target-dir /user/hive/warehouse/xxxx.db/testing_columns \
    --outdir /home/xxxxx/logs/outdir
```

Also consider that according to the [Sqoop User Guide](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html):

> The facility of using free-form query in the current version of Sqoop
>   is limited to simple queries where there are no ambiguous projections
>   and no `OR` conditions in the `WHERE` clause. Use of complex queries such
>   as queries that have sub-queries or joins leading to ambiguous
>   projections can lead to unexpected results.